# Working with PyQt4

Tags: python, widget, pyqt, runtime

I''ve been experimenting with PyQt4 and I'm having a hard time with getting it to run the way I need it to. What I'm looking for is a way to have my own code run in a widget independent of gui events.  Is there something like an 'onRender' command for your widget to run bckground code?

Comment: You should show some code.

Comment: You can override some methods of any widget...